# Dynamic children objects in dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have code:

```js
locales.addString('en_us', 'example:child', 'value')
locales.addString('en_us', 'secondEx:child:secondChild', 'value')
```

So `en_us` object needs to be like:

```js
const obj = {
  en_us: {
    example: { child: "value" },
    secondEx: { child: { secondChild: "value" } }
  }
}
```

How do I need to make this possible?

UPD: I know how to make dynamic keys but I don't know how to make dynamic object with those keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use lodash set function aka: `_.set`:

```js
const _ = require("lodash");

const obj = {};

const locales = {
  addString: (key, path, value) => {
    obj[key] = obj[key] || {};
    _.set(obj[key], path.replace(/:/g, "."), value);
  },
};
locales.addString("en_us", "example:child", "value");
locales.addString("en_us", "secondEx:child:secondChild", "value");

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "  "));
```

outputs:

```sh
{
  "en_us": {
    "example": {
      "child": "value"
    },
    "secondEx": {
      "child": {
        "secondChild": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know. Thanks!